# React JSX: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, loops, jsx

There are probably many questions that might cover this error, but I've looked for quite some time and can't seem to find an answer that fits this problem There seems to be an infinite loop being created as I pass one prop from class to another. I've made sure that the buttons are bound and only activate once but this didnt seem to help.

NAVBAR CLASS:

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = ({
        page: "Home",

    });
    this.Home = this.Home.bind(this);
}
 Home = (row) => {
        switch(row ){
        case "Home":
            this.setState({page: "Home"}) 
            break;
        case "Schedule":
            this.setState({page: "Schedule"}) 
            break;
        case "Experts":
            this.setState({page: "Experts"}) 
            break;
        case "Hotel":
            this.setState({page: "Hotel"}) 
            break;
        case "Register":
            this.setState({page: "Register"}) 
            break;
        case "Reviews":
            this.setState({page: "Reviews"}) 
            break;
        default: 
            this.setState({page: "Home"}) 
            break;
        }
    }

render() {

    function HamMenu(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            menuToggle = 'btn active';
        }
    let menuToggle = 'btn not-active';
    console.log("state: " + this.state.page);
    return(
        <div>
        <nav className="navbar fixed-top navbar-default navbar-light bg-light">
            <div className="container">
                <img className="navbar-logo" src="https://southbankresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2019/08/stickyLogo-min.png" width="200px"/>
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.Home("Home")}>WHY ATTEND?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.Home("Schedule")} >SCHEDULE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.Home("Experts")}>EXPERTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.Home("Hotel")}>HOTEL</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.Home("Register")}>REGISTER</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.Home("Reviews")}>REVIEWS</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                 <div className="box">
                    <div onClick={HamMenu} className={menuToggle}>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </nav>
        <Body page={this.state.page}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

BODY CLASS:

```
class Body extends React.Component {
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
        currentPage: "",

    });
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    let page = this.props.page;
    switch(page ){
        case "Home":
            this.setState({currentPage: <Home/>}) 
            break;
        case "Schedule":
            this.setState({currentPage: <Schedule/>}) 
            break;
        case "Experts":
            this.setState({currentPage: "Experts"}) 
            break;
        case "Hotel":
            this.setState({currentPage: "Hotel"}) 
            break;
        case "Register":
            this.setState({currentPage: "Register"}) 
            break;
        case "Reviews":
            this.setState({currentPage: "Reviews"}) 
            break;
        default: 
            this.setState({currentPage: "Home"}) 
        }
}

render() {
    console.log(this.props.page)
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.currentPage}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

[image]

Thank you for your time, and again I apologise if this question has been answered before in an old thread. Cheers

Comment: why this: `this.setState({currentPage: <Home/>})`?

Comment: Can you include a snapshot for the error message? it might give some info about where it happens.

Comment: Your `render` function is calling `this.Home`, which calls `setState`. When you modify state, it causes another `render`. You're stuck in a loop.

Comment: Try writing another function to handle the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a check for changed props in your `componentDidUpdate`. Try adding it:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  let page = this.props.page;
  if (prevProps.page !== page) {
    switch (page) {
      case "Home":
        this.setState({
          currentPage: < Home / >
        })
        break;
      case "Schedule":
        this.setState({
          currentPage: < Schedule / >
        })
        break;
      case "Experts":
        this.setState({
          currentPage: "Experts"
        })
        break;
      case "Hotel":
        this.setState({
          currentPage: "Hotel"
        })
        break;
      case "Register":
        this.setState({
          currentPage: "Register"
        })
        break;
      case "Reviews":
        this.setState({
          currentPage: "Reviews"
        })
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({
          currentPage: "Home"
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Also to keep your method more DRY, you can call `this.setState` only once:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  let page = this.props.page;
  if (prevProps.page !== page) {
    let currentPage;
    switch (page) {
      case "Home":
        currentPage = < Home / >
        break;
      case "Schedule":
        currentPage = < Schedule / >
        break;
      case "Experts":
        currentPage = "Experts"
        break;
      case "Hotel":
        currentPage = "Hotel"
        break;
      case "Register":
        currentPage = "Register"
        break;
      case "Reviews":
        currentPage = "Reviews"
        break;
      default:
        currentPage = "Home"
    }
    this.setState({currentPage});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.
So the solution of that is wrapping that part in a condition or using React-Router library for react routing as follows.

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><Link to="/Home">WHY ATTEND?</li>
   <li><Link to="/Scheudle">SCHEDULE</li>
</ul>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>  
    <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/Schedule" component={Schudule} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```